# SQL - How do I replace/modify strings in multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a lot of rows in database where column "info" is ie. **"Size, inch: 12x13`<br>`Material: paper`<br>`Amount: 100pcs"**. Now I need to find/select all rows that has this string part "Size, inch:" and replace/fix those rows' colums to ie. **"Size: 12x13 inch`<br>` Material: paper`<br>`Amount: 100pcs "**.

How in the world I write a sql statement for this? Do I need some magic regexp for sql? How do I replace and modify parts of a string in multiple rows?

EDIT: The numbers can be anything (ie. 12x13 or 44x55 or 77x88x99 etc.) So there would have to be some kind of wildcard for the numbers, perhaps?

I need to change "Size, inch: 'anynumbershere' 'anythingafter the numbers'" to "Size: 'anynumbershere' inch 'anythingafter'".

Comment: Check for mysql `replace` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
update mytable set info=REPLACE ( info , 'Size, inch: 12x13 ', 'Size: 12x13 inch' )
where info like '%inch:12X13%'
```

Comment: My numbers 12x13 are different in every row. I'm not sure this works. In some rows there can be ie. "Size, inch: 45x88x99<br> and so on..."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
update table t
    info = replace(replace(info, 'Size inch:', 'Size:'), '<br>Material', ' inch<br>Material')
    where info like 'Size inch:%<br>Material%';
```

Note:  this assumes that `'Size inch'` and `'<br>Material'` only appear once in each string.

Comment: The "material" after <br> isn't always there. This is my point why this is painful. I need to change "Size, inch: <anynumbershere><anythingafter the numbers>" to "Size: <anynumbershere> inch<anythingafter>".

Comment: @H3ll1n . . . We can only answer the question that is asked.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question.

Comment: My bad. I got too specific.